# How do I match and return a zero with a regular expression in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to extract a number from a string. The number might be zero. Numbers appear like this: '+123', '-8' or '0'.

```
alert( '+123'.match(/[-?|+?]\d+/) );
alerts +123

alert( '-8'.match(/[-?|+?]\d+/) );
alerts -8

alert( '0'.match(/[-?|+?]\d+/) );
alerts null // why oh why?
```

How do I get '0'.match(/[-?|+?]\d+/) to return 0 instead of null?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The pattern

```
[-?|+?]
```

will match exactly one `-`, `+`, `|` or a `?`. What you want is

```
[-+]?
```

which will match a `-` or a `+` one or zero times.

This will allow numbers like '123' to pass as well. If you require the + sign, use this:

```
/0|[-+][1-9]\d*/
```

Comment: Which is not what he wants. A number has only one prefix (if any)

Comment: @Sean: I don't understand. Any counterexample?

Comment: My bad, I misread :) But that last regexp looks like overkill, unless its important to disallow -0/+0

Comment: @Sean: I think you misread the answer.  The final regex provided is an alternative if the `+` or `-` is required when the number is not `0`.  It will allow only one prefix.

Comment: @Andy, indeed I did - still haven't got my first cup of coffee :)

Comment: @Sean: tell me about it, can't get good help these days ;-) */end of hijack*

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
var rePattern = /[+-]?\d+/;

"0".match(rePattern) // 0
"+44".match(rePattern) //+44
"-3".match(rePattern) //-3
```

Note this is not as strict as Kenny's